# Regex to get square brackets containing numbers only but are not within square brackets themselves

Tags: c#, .net, regex

**Sample String**

```
 "[] [ds*[000112]] [1448472995] sample string [1448472995] ***";
```

The regex should match

```
 [1448472995] [1448472995]
```

and should not match `[000112]` since there is outer square bracket.

Currently I have this regex that is matching `[000112]`  as well

```
const string unixTimeStampPattern = @"\[([0-9]+)]";
```

Comment: In other words, you want to match a bracketed number only if the same number of (balanced) opening and closing brackets follow?

Comment: You have to use balanced text regex to exclude nested brackets.

Comment: @Tim : Yes you are right.

Comment: I guess you do not need any balancing groups: just check for a `]` after the `\[\d+]` pattern with a lookahead: [`\[\d+](?!\S*])`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%5cd%2b%5d(%3f!%5cS*%5d)&i=%5b%5d+%5bds*%5b000112%5d%5d+%5b1448472995%5d+sample+string+%5b1448472995%5d+***). If it works for you, I will post with explanations.

Comment: And yet `\[\d+](?!\S*])` relies on a whitespace delimiter and fails for [\[1448472995\]or\[999\]](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%5cd%2b%5d(%3f!%5cS*%5d)&i=%5b1448472995%5dor%5b999%5d) and passes for [\[\[1448472995\] *\[999\]\]](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%5cd%2b%5d(%3f!%5cS*%5d)&i=%5b%5b1448472995%5d+*%5b999%5d%5d)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good way to do it using balanced text.

```
    ( \[ \d+ \] )                 # (1)
 |                             # or,
    \[                            # Opening bracket
    (?>                           # Then either match (possessively):
         [^\[\]]+                      #  non - brackets
      |                              # or
         \[                            #  [ increase the bracket counter
         (?<Depth> )
      |                              # or
         \]                            #  ] decrease the bracket counter
         (?<-Depth> )
    )*                            # Repeat as needed.
    (?(Depth)                     # Assert that the bracket counter is at zero
         (?!)
    )
    \]                            # Closing bracket
```

C# sample

```
string sTestSample = "[] [ds*[000112]] [1448472995] sample string [1448472995] ***";
Regex RxBracket = new Regex(@"(\[\d+\])|\[(?>[^\[\]]+|\[(?<Depth>)|\](?<-Depth>))*(?(Depth)(?!))\]");

Match bracketMatch = RxBracket.Match(sTestSample);
while (bracketMatch.Success)
{
    if (bracketMatch.Groups[1].Success)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", bracketMatch);
    bracketMatch = bracketMatch.NextMatch();
}
```

Output

```
[1448472995]
[1448472995]
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [**balancing groups**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html) to handle this - it looks a bit daunting but isn't all that complicated:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"\[               # Match opening bracket.
    \d+                # Match a number.
    \]                 # Match closing bracket.
    (?=                # Assert that the following can be matched ahead:
     (?>               # The following group (made atomic to avoid backtracking):
      [^\[\]]+         # One or more characters except brackets
     |                 # or
      \[ (?<Depth>)    # an opening bracket (increase bracket counter)
     |                 # or
      \] (?<-Depth>)   # a closing bracket (decrease bracket counter, can't go below 0).
     )*                # Repeat ad libitum.
     (?(Depth)(?!))    # Assert that the bracket counter is now zero.
     [^\[\]]*          # Match any remaining non-bracket characters
     \z                # until the end of the string.
    )                  # End of lookahead.", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Comment: This takes a prohibitively long time when it validates brackets past the `[\d+]` every time. You can test this by catenating copies of the test string. I did 2000 copies, waited 5 minutes, it never came back. Mine came back in 1 second. It's probably faster to validate balanced brackets on the string separately, ahead of time. Then do a simple alternation.

Comment: @Tim : Thanks!!! that was helpful. I am trying to cope up with the parsing logic :). I need to get square brackets in a match and number as a group of the match, Since my match should be replaced by DateTime derived from unixTime. I could match the opening bracket by simply (?<=\[)  replacing this with \] but could not figure out how to match the closing bracet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to capture the unix time stamp? Then you can try a simpler one where you specify the minimum number of characters matched in a group.

```
\[([0-9]{10})\]
```

Here I limit it to 10 characters since I doubt the time stamp will hit 11 characters anytime soon... To protect against that:

```
\[([0-9]{10,11})\]
```

Of course this could lead to false positives if you have a 10-length number in an enclosing bracket.

Answer (score -2):

This will match your expression as expected: http://regexr.com/3csg3 it uses lookahead.

Comment: First, please don't post answers that only link to external sites. Second, your regex fails as soon as the second closing parenthesis doesn't immediately follow the first one, as in `[foo [1234] bar]`.